# Accessing the date from a timestamp query result rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I am writing a script and I do a query to the database to get the last entered timestamp in the table. So the result that I get back is this:

```
#<UtilityReading timestamp: "2013-02-18 23:30:00">
```

I am just wondering how do I access just the date from the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UtilityReading is in an variable called `@utility`, for example, then you would just call `@utility.timestamp.to_date`.

Comment: `last_date_entered = UtilityReading.select(:timestamp).order(:timestamp).last`

This is my query that I am using so the timestamp is being stored in the variable last_date_entered.

Comment: Then use `last_date_entered.timestamp.to_date`.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
@utility.timestamp.to_date
```